# How do I make an artistic out of focus image in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do I make an artistic out of focus image like the ones in the Playbook background or soft images. My goal is to make beautiful and or subtle backgrounds.

[image: blurred image]

[image: soft image]

I'm trying to learn more design guidance instead of "run the Blur filter" in Photoshop. For example, take a hi-res image and zoom into a small part of it.

Comment: According to [Russel Brown](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTYcRWPsZUg&list=PL8776E00BAFB19D73&index=1&feature=plpp_video), it actually is that easy (in Photoshop CS6).

Comment: Interesting video. He seems pretty excited about it ...and I'd have to agree. :) After thinking about it I'd have to say I'm trying to attain a technique rather than a tool if that makes sense?

Comment: @slhck - ok i updated it. nice feature!

Answer (score 3):

I would set my bush shape big and fat, dapple the different colored blobs in different layers, dial up the opacity on the layers and/or make a mask layer for each and put a radial gradient fill over the blobs.
Finally dose them with Gaussian filter, both the image and the mask.

Comment: @1.2gigawatts When trying to "subtle" a background, lowering the picture "brightness" is what I like. I actually prefer in focus, just laid back because it is dampened in brightness. "box" and "surface" blur can be better for whole page blur sometimes. Streaking , grain , and artifacting when getting "subtle" I do not like, without detail the minor color seperations can "band" making it a hard thing to perfect. Compression can take a great soft look and turn it bad, an "expert" photo might not crunch size so much  , just depends , and depends some on the display. Good luck.

Comment: @Psycogeek Great warning and advice about subtle shading and compression.